# Swapping multiple instances of two characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, swap

I'd like to find, if possible, a more succinct or elegant way to swap every occurrence of two specific characters in a string, but still readable and easy to understand, i.e. something akin to `a, b = b, a` for variables.

For example, say I want to swap the characters `X` and `Y` in the following string : `"AAAXYAYXAXX"` → `"AAAYXAXYAYY"`.

The way I'm doing it currently is

```
text = text.replace("B", "tempB").replace("A", "B").replace("tempB", "A")
```

but I'm wondering if there may be a better way.

Comment: See `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `translate` and `maketrans`.

```
def swap_characters(text, char1, char2):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans(char1 + char2, char2 + char1))
```

`str.maketrans()` creates a translation table that maps char1 to char2 and vice versa. Then, `text.translate()` applies the translation table to the input string